# Find all files matching desription and create hard link in directory

Tags: linux, find, ln

I would like to find all `.mkv` files in my download directory and create a hard link to them in my `/movies/` directory.

Here’s what I have so far:

```
for i in `find /download/ -name *.mkv`; do ln "$i" /movies/; done
```

Which *almost* works: I receive a bunch of hard links to partial file names. That is, instead of a hard link to say `The Best Movie Ever.mkv` I receive four hard links, one to `The` one to `Best` one to `Movie` and one to `Ever.mkv`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
find /download/ -name *.mkv -exec ln {} /movies/ \;
```

Comment: Sweet. It works. I was so close at one point, I had this answer except for the last '\' Thanks

Comment: Man page says you have to escape the ';' so bash doesn't interpret it